# Embed crystal reports designer in windows application

Tags: crystal-reports

We have crystal reports 2008 full version. We want to embed crystal reports designer in windows application. The goal is to limit functionality and make it part of existing application just for appearance. This application is meant for end user and they should be able to change/edit report design. e.g. cosmetic changes change font, text size, width positions of textbox, line etc.

First of all is it possible to integrate standard crystal report designer in windows application? (environment Visual studio. )

If yes, any sample application or tutorial link?

Thanks. btw, I am fairly new to crystal reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend this approach.  Even if it's technically possible, it would be complicated to build and run.  Plus, I can forsee the end-user asking you to "save" certain combinations.

My alternative approach:  Based on the data, make a few (<=3) "templates" that will let the majority of the data look good.  The end-user can choose from the "template" which best fits their data.

Tip: You've already made all the report files on the server.  The end-user is just picking which one they want to see.

Example: The end-user is running a report which only has small numbers.  They choose the "small numbers" template.  You already generated this report, so you don't have to worry about licensing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for CR later versions, but in earlier ones (CR9) such functionality existed. Unfortunately it was not royalty-free - each **user** licence costed about $200 or more, volume (OEM) discounts apply.

I think situation is similar currently - report design functionality is core business of CR and this won't ever be free.